# How to SELECT fields from SQL LOGIN on microsoft sql server management studio 2012

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

Anyone can help me? I need to select the username and password of the accounts of user from SQL Login using PDO. I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio where I can't find the fields of the username and password because the accounts are in master database. Thanks!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-syslogins-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017. But what are you really want to do?

Comment: I want to connect my php to the database and select the accounts (username and password) stored in logins of mssms.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to do here is to retrieve the Username and Password of the SQL Server Users, Currently there is no option to retire the Users Password, but you can retrieve all the uses available on the server using the following query :

```
select * from master.sys.server_principals
```

If you have the admin privilege, then you can reset the password using the UI or using the Alter statement like this

```
ALTER LOGIN [LOGIN_NAME] WITH PASSWORD=N’NewPassword’
```

But you can never retrieve the same

Comment: I am trying to make a UI where account with a specific username will be reset to its default password.

Comment: then you can use the above statements. Use the first select toe list the usernames and then run the alter statement with the selected user name to reset to Default password

Comment: We already selected the usernames however the password cant be updated to default, i am using `$_GET` by passing value.

Comment: if you have the user name, then execute the ALTER statement by passing your User name and Default password to it. The Password will be reset. Otherwise Please check your PHP code is correct.

Comment: I am using Update statement does it affect or should i use ALTER inside php code?

Also i am getting all the same value after $_GET where i have the same parameter when selecting and passing value.

Comment: Update is for Tables and Since User is different type of Object, you should use ALTER

Comment: `$name = $_GET['name'];`
`$sql = "ALTER LOGIN $name WITH PASSWORD=N'Nico1234!'";`
`$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);`
`$stmt->bindParam(':name', $_GET['name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);`
`$stmt->execute();`
Bro i am having a problem here its not altering :(

Comment: @NicoGestiada I'm not an expert in PHP. so can you please confirm that the Data binding is correct in php Code

Comment: Okay, My PHP is correct i dont know if the query is correct or not.